# Find element with python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

How can I find element like html:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="D"> 4 </div>          < --- I NEED TO GET NUMBER 
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a bunch of class="A", but not all have a class="B"!

I already get every class "B" in object like :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("B")
```

It's working well!

But then, when I do a 'for' with every element of 'elements' :

```
number = int(element.find_element_by_xpath("/div[@class='D']").text)
```

error message appears "unable to locate an element with the xpath expression... not a valid XPATH expression."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is not valid because it's missing a `/`

```
/div[@class='D']
```

should be

```
//div[@class='D']
^ added
```

It may be easier to use a CSS selector here

```
.A>.B>.D
```

Code

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".A>.B>.D")
```

If there's only one of them or you want only the first one, you can use `.find_element()` instead and skip the loop.

Comment: "//" isn't working :'( same error...
There is other conditions that's why I need to use a for...
However I can find the div bellow class="B" with a "..//", but not the div inside class="B" with "//"

Comment: @Deïkoz You've not pasted the code you are actually working with or not using the XPath as I've typed it. That is a valid XPath. You shouldn't be getting the "not a valid XPATH expression" as you stated in your question.

Comment: You need to use the ".." whenever you are searching from an existing element, e.g. `element.find_element_by_xpath("..//div[@class='D']").text`.

Comment: You probably need to post more of your code... post a [mcve].